# How can i get the task id of a workflow?

Tags: designer-workflow, sharepoint-rest-api, task-list, workflow-tasks-list

How can i get the task Id of a workflow task?

I tried to get it by using paralel blocks, like this

[image]

With the parallel block, I do two things:

1. Create the task
2. Get the task ID with Rest API

To get the Task ID, I use the field "**WF4InstanceId**", with a descending order, by Id and taking only the first row and before that I wait for 2 minutes.

Request URL:

```
 _api/web/lists/getByTitle('*ListName*')/items?$select=ID,WF4InstanceId&$filter=WF4InstanceId eq '*WorkflowInstanceId'&$top=1&$orderby=Id desc
```

Using the Request URL with a extension, it throws the correct row

[image]

But in the workflow it doesn't.

[image]

And, if do the request (With the Request URL of the workflow history), it works

[image]

Also working directly in the chrome but in xml. (Because lack of headers)

[image]

I don't know what can i do to fix that or if there is another way to get the task id.

Can someone help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is details descriptive steps on how to get task id from SharePoint designer workflow:

The workflow needs to perform some actions in parallel, sort of, and a “HTTP Web Service Action”.
The web service can get the ID of the latest Task by using the following URL

[%Workflow Context:Current Site URL%] /sites/mySite/_api/web/lists/getbytitle('tasks')/items?$top=1&$orderby=Id%20desc

Using this URL in a “Call HTTP web service” to return “ResponseContent”

The next action is get item from dictionary

Get d/results(0) from Variable: ResponseContent (Output to Variable: ResponseContent )

Following with this

Get Id from Variable: ResponseContent (Output to Variable: TaskId )

This can only work if the workflow runs in a parallel block but with a tweak to run slightly after – this ensures the task item is definitely there.

Setting up the call web service can be done in this way

Do the web service setup steps as normal then add a parallel block

Add and configure start task process into it

The following actions will run in parallel: Start a task process with Variable: Region (Task outcome to Variable: Outcome1 )

Then add an If block

If Current Item:ID is greater than 0

This allows a run of actions sequentially (but still in parallel to the task). Without this the next steps would all trigger at the same time.

Add a pause before continuing just to ensure the task IS created

Pause for 0 days, 0 hours, 1 minutes

Then call the web service

Call [URL]... HTTP web service with request (ResponseContent to Variable: ResponseContent |ResponseHeaders to responseHeaders |ResponseStatusCode to Variable: responseCode1 )

Manage the results

Get d/results(0) from Variable: ResponseContent (Output to Variable: ResponseContent ) Get Id from Variable: ResponseContent (Output to Variable: TaskId )

You can then update an item in a list using the newly found TaskId

Reference :

[SharePoint Designer 2013 Workflows – How to get Task Process ID](https://www.google.com/amp/s/stuff-for-sharepoint.com/2017/10/13/sharepoint-designer-2013-workflows-how-to-get-task-process-id/amp/)